# Terraform removes Azure function app binaries

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I have deployed an Azure Function App using terraform, sometimes when I update some configurations on the function (AppSettings for example), Terraform remove all binaries which are deployed by the dev from Azure DevOps !

It seems that this happens randomly, because on another similar environments the binaries stay there.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function" {
  count                         = length(var.function)
  name                          = ""
  location                      = ""
  resource_group_name           = ""
  service_plan_id               = ""
  
  storage_account_name          = ""
  storage_account_access_key    = ""
  
  https_only                    = "true"
  
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = []
  }
  
  site_config {
    application_stack {
        dotnet_version              =  ""
        use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = "false"
    }
    
    always_on                   = false
    health_check_path           = "/test"
    http2_enabled               = true
    use_32_bit_worker           = false
    
    application_insights_connection_string = connection_string
    application_insights_key               = instrumentation_key
    
    ip_restriction {
            name = ""
            action = ""
            priority = value
            service_tag = ""
    }
    
    
  }

  app_settings = {
        AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT           = lookup(var.function[count.index], "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT")
        DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT                    = lookup(var.function[count.index], "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT                = lookup(var.function[count.index], "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
        WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE       = lookup(var.function[count.index], "SYNC_UPDATE", null)
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME              = "dotnet"
        FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION           = "~4"
        "PARAM" = join("",["@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=", name, "; SecretName=value;SecretVersion=value"])
  }
  
  connection_string {
    name = "CosmosDB"
    type = "Custom"
    value = ""
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  tags = ""
}
```

Comment: The plan output should show you what's being changed and should tell you why it's being replaced

Comment: The plan show me that only some params will be updated on the appSettings and not removal of the deployed binaries

Comment: Be very careful when using count for deployment of resources. The pitfalls of doing so are well-documented, basically terraform is likely destroying and re-creating the Azure function resources for no good reason, which has the appearance of the binaries being removed. As @ChrisDoyle said, consult your output with care and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Can you try adding `prevent_destroy = true`- in the `life cycle` block to prevent destroying resources automatically. @admin

Answer (score 0):

> I have deployed an Azure Function App using terraform, sometimes when I update some configurations on the function (AppSettings for example), Terraform remove all binaries which are deployed: -

There are two ways to prevent this issue as detailed below.

***Firstly,*** instead of including empty in the `ignore_changes = []`, add `app_settings` under `ignore_changes = [app_settings]`. Adding in this way applies changes only to the app settings by keeping the remaining code as same.

You can also add `prevent_destroy = true` which helps in preventing the resources from deleting unfortunately.

```bash
lifecycle  {
  prevent_destroy = true
  ignore_changes = [
    app_settings
 ]
}
```

Referring to the sample [terraform template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#example-usage-python-in-a-consumption-plan), I have applied above configuration and executed the template which leads to a successful deployment as shown below.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "jahnavi-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "linuxfunctionjah"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "jahplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example" {
  name                = "jahfunction-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  
  app_settings={
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "python"
        ..Add settings as per your requirement
      }

  site_config {}

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [
        app_settings
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

***Second*** one is using [`azurerm_management_lock`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/management_lock) for the resources under a specific or required scope. It will also help in preventing the resources from deleting unexpectedly or due to any other dependencies.